# grep a tar.gz file where tar contains other gz files

Tags: grep, tar, gzip, zgrep

I have a tar gz file. Inside the file are other directories and gz files and I am trying to recursively grep for a string. I have tried zgrep but the string I am searching for is not outputted even though I know it is there. What would be the command to do this?. The gz files inside the tar.gz files are *xml.gz files about 10k files.

Comment: show your trial code

Comment: I tried this but no output. I had to unzip all the files in a DIR and run the normal grep on them and that worked but wanted a way to not have to un-tar and unzip........  saw this command on stack.. ...................................                                                                                     find -name \*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep "STRING"